How to localize ng-bootstrap datepicker specifically using moment locale?
I'm using ng-bootstrap DatePicker in my Angular project.
Without specifically specifying I18N_VALUES values for each language and utilizing the moment library, I have to internationalize it and dynamically change the language. Please, let me.
Here is a Stackblitz example:
Stackblitz

This question is similar to: Internationalization of ng-bootstrap. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

They key changes are:
We should import the locale data as shown in the below method, for all the languages the date picker supports:
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';

Then, we can get rid of locale property and just directly update the I18n service which contains the language which the datepicker uses.
@Injectable()
export class DatepicketLocalizationService extends NgbDatepickerI18n {
  private locale: string;
  constructor(private _i18n: I18n, private localeService: LocaleService) {
    super();
    this.localeService.locale$.subscribe((locale) => {
      this._i18n.language = locale;
    });
  }

  getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {
    console.log(
      this._i18n.language,
      moment()
        .locale(this._i18n.language)
        .weekday(weekday - 1)
        .format('dd'),
      moment().locale()
    );
    return moment()
      .locale(this._i18n.language)
      .weekday(weekday - 1)
      .format('dd');
  }

Then finally, there is no simple method to make the datepicker reload to the new locale, but I was able to get it working using the below code. Ideally there should be a simple refresh button that re-renders the datepicker.
refreshDatepicker() {
  if (this.datepicker) {
    console.log('refresh 1');
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.datepicker.focus();
    this.datepicker._service.focusSelect();
  }
}

Full Code:
datepicker.component.ts
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  Injectable,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { LocaleService } from './localeService.service';
import { NgbDatepicker } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbDate } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-i18n',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.template.html',
})
export class DatePickerComponent {
  model: NgbDateStruct;
  @ViewChild('dp', { static: true }) datepicker: NgbDatepicker;

  constructor(
    private localeService: LocaleService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  changeLocale(locale: string) {
    this.localeService.setLocale(locale);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.localeService.locale$.subscribe(() => {
      this.refreshDatepicker();
    });
  }

    refreshDatepicker() {
      if (this.datepicker) {
        console.log('refresh 1');
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
        this.datepicker.focus();
        this.datepicker._service.focusSelect();
      }
    }
}

datepicker-localization.service.ts
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDatepickerI18n, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { LocaleService } from './localeService.service';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';

@Injectable()
export class I18n {
  language = 'de';
}

@Injectable()
export class DatepicketLocalizationService extends NgbDatepickerI18n {
  private locale: string;
  constructor(private _i18n: I18n, private localeService: LocaleService) {
    super();
    this.localeService.locale$.subscribe((locale) => {
      this._i18n.language = locale;
    });
  }

  getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {
    console.log(
      this._i18n.language,
      moment()
        .locale(this._i18n.language)
        .weekday(weekday - 1)
        .format('dd'),
      moment().locale()
    );
    return moment()
      .locale(this._i18n.language)
      .weekday(weekday - 1)
      .format('dd');
  }

  getMonthShortName(month: number): string {
    return moment()
      .locale(this._i18n.language)
      .month(month - 1)
      .format('MMM');
  }

  getMonthFullName(month: number): string {
    return moment()
      .locale(this._i18n.language)
      .month(month - 1)
      .format('MMMM');
  }

  getDayAriaLabel(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    return moment([date.year, date.month - 1, date.day])
      .locale(this._i18n.language)
      .format('LL');
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Months are not being translated. It seems that month getMonthShortName is not triggered.  Thank you for the quick replay
